# How to get Visual Studio 2017 editor to support a different coding style?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

The coding style that my employer uses states that the brace `{` should go on the same line, not the next one.  Example:

```
class bar {
  private void foo() {
      if (1) {
        Console.WriteLine("great");
      } else {
        Console.WriteLine("also great");
      }
  }
}
```

Visual Studio's default is to place braces on their own line.
How can I get Visual Studio to respect this coding style?

Comment: What coding style states that?  AFAIK the C# design guidelines state that it should be on its own line...

Comment: Sounds like your coding style was written by a Java developer?

Comment: @maccettura My employer's style.  I believe they adopted it from airbnb's published styles.

Comment: @oerkelens I don't like either, but that's the style.

Comment: Use the options, Luke.

Comment: From airbnb? I get a lot of hits on airbnb coding style for _Javascript_. Why on earth would someone think of applying JS style to C#? Hell, why not go for COBOL style then? That's also a programming language, and it has clear coding style guides available :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VS 2017 you can use the following Option; TextEditor -> C# -> Code Style -> Formating -> New Lines:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

(I don't have 2017, but this is what I see in 2015, so it may be similar.)

Under Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Formatting -> New Lines, there are several options for "Place open brace on new line for <X>" (where X may be  "types" or "methods", etc), as well as "Place <X> on new line", where X is "else" or "catch" or "members in anonymous types".

You can check and uncheck these boxes as required to match the style your company sets up.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it is called K&R style. I use [JetBrains ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/?fromMenu), but it is not free.

[image]

Comment: This functionality is built into VS. No need for Resharper.